# CSS selector to choose second item after a hyphen

Tags: css, css-selectors

The CSS selector `[attr|=value]` is designed to select items which are exactly "value" or which begin with "value-". This was originally intended to allow selection of all languages regardless of dialect, such as "en-au", "en-ca", "en-gb", "en-us".

What I'm looking for is a selector for an item which is exactly "value", which includes "-value-" or which ends with "-value". In my case, I am not concerned with language codes at all.

[This page](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/attribute/) claims that there is a `=\`operator:

```
[data-value=|"foo"] {
  /* Attribute value has this in a dash-separated list somewhere */
}
```

However I have been unable to  get this to work. If I'm just interested in a controlled list of 2-item terms, then this will work for me:

```
[attr*=-value][attr$=value]
```

However, this would also return items like "xx-valuevalue", so the result is not perfect.

My question is: is there another way to write a CSS selector that will select all items that have a given string as one item in a hyphen-delimited list?

Comment: Just combine them? [attr="value"], [attr^="value-"], [attr*="-value-"],[attr$="-value"]{}

Comment: FYI, the technical term for the `-us` part of `en-us` is not "dialect, but "region".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
[attr*=-value-], [attr$=-value], [attr=value]
```

In pseudo code:

> Get those containing `-value-`, those ending with `-value`, and those exactly equal to `value`.

Comment: Thanks for showing me that selectors can be combined using a comma. However, the first part of your answer does not work for me. In pseudo-code, it says "choose all items that begin with 'value' or 'value-', except for those that begin with 'value'", which results in an empty set. Have I misunderstood something?

Comment: @JamesNewton I just edited my answer. Is that clear?

Comment: In my experience, `[attr|=value]` will match "value" and"value-something", but not "something-value". Is your experience different?